# How to host elastic search on IIS Server

Tags: iis, elasticsearch

I want to host elastic search on IIS, so that i can consume it in my app.

Right now I am running it on localhost and able to access it using console application.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This should get you started: https://www.ulyaoth.net/resources/tutorial-install-logstash-and-kibana-on-a-windows-server.34/

Comment: Thankyou, It seems helpful. I am going apply it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To host elastic search on IIS, I found the link [ulyaoth.net/resources](https://www.ulyaoth.net/resources/tutorial-install-logstash-and-kibana-on-a-windows-server.34/)  provided by **Val** very useful.
Trying to write minimum steps that works for me.

1. Install Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.0 or above in your IIS
   (if not available).
2. In Web Platform Installer, Search for "Application Request Routing
   3.0". (you can type ARR to filter/search this). And Install.
3. Open IIS Manager.
4. Create a website. In Physical path, fill path of "Elastic Search".
5. Create Reverse Proxy.

Bingo, Now your elastic search is available on website url. To run elastic search in background. you can run this as service. For detail info use above link.